# hook_form_alter not working in comment form Validation

Tags: forms

I am trying to apply a hook for comment form email validation but it is not working.

```
function ajax_comments_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'comment_migrate_example_advanced_comment_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'ajax_comments_custom_validation_function'; // this adds your validation function to the stack
  }
}

function ajax_comments_custom_validation_function(&$form, &$form_state){
  $email = $form_state['values']['mail']['und'][0]['value'];
  $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/';
  if (!preg_match($regex, $email)) {
      form_set_error('mail', t('Invalid Email.' ));
    }
}
```

I am using the following code in ajax comment module's .module file. What am I doing Wrong here? Please help. When I try to submit the form it gives Ajax Error.

Comment: Hi @Lokeshwari, are you sure, its entering the validation, just check if the form_id is correct

Comment: @Lokeshwari Can you post ajax error also here.

Comment: it says you cannot use $form state object as array in function ajax_comment_validation_function

Comment: form id is correct i tried echo $form_id and it returned this value for the comment form

Comment: also i would like to add a point here when i try to echo hello in hook function it gets printed but in the validation function if i try the same nothing gets printed